# Use fopen to open file repeatedly in C

Tags: c, fopen

I have a question about "fopen" function.

```
FILE *pFile1, *pFile2;
pFile1 = fopen(fileName,"rb+");
pFile2 = fopen(fileName,"rb+");
```

Can I say that pFile1==pFile2? Besides, can FILE type be used as a key of map?

Thanks!

Comment: No `pFile` will not be the same as `pFile2`. Try it

Comment: ..And also why using `stdio` a=for C++. Of course if you are preverse you can use it as a key. After all it is just a series of bits but what are you trying to prove

Comment: No, and those two pointers will not be the same and you would not want that behavior either. `FILE*` is more than a pointer to a named stream in this example... each one has its own state such as the current position.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I say that `pFile1 == pFile2`?

No `pFile1` and `pFile2` are pointers to two *distinct* `FILE` structures, returned by the two different function calls.

Give it a try!!

To add further:

Note opening a file that is already open has implementation-defined behavior, according to the C Standard:

> #### [FIO31-C. Do not open a file that is already open](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO31-C.+Do+not+open+a+file+that+is+already+open)
>
> subclause 7.21.3, paragraph 8 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]:
>
> Functions that open additional (nontemporary) ﬁles require a file
> name, which is a string. The rules for composing valid ﬁle names are
> implementation-deﬁned. Whether the same file can be simultaneously
> open multiple times is also implementation-deﬁned.

Some platforms may forbid a file simultaneously being opened multiple times, but other platforms may allow it. Therefore, portable code cannot depend on what will happen if this rule is violated. Although this isn't a problem on POSIX compliant systems. Many applications open a file multiple times to read concurrently (of-course if you wants writing operation also then you may need concurrency control mechanism, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Any mistake in answer?

Answer (score 3):

#### Can I say that pFile1==pFile2?

*(edited after reading the pertinent remark of Grijesh Chauhan)*

you can say that pFile1 != pFile2, because 2 things can happen:

1. the system forbids opening the file twice, in which case pFile2 will be NULL
2. the system allows a second opening, i, which case pFile2 will point to a different context.

This is one more reason among thousands to check system calls, by the way.

Assuming the second call succeeded you can,for instance, seek to a given position with pFile1 while you read from another with pFile2.

*As a side note, since you will eventually access the same physical disk, it is rarely a good idea to do so unless you know exactly what you're doing. Seeking back and forth like crazy between two different parts of a big file could eventually force the disk driver to wobble between two physical parts of the disk, reducing your I/O performance dramatically (unless the disk is a non-seeking device like an SSD).*

#### can FILE type be used as a key of map?

No, because

1. it would not make any sense to use an unknown structure of an unknown size whose lifetime you have no direct control of as a key
2. the FILE class does not implement the necessary comparison operator

You *could* use a `FILE *`, though, since any pointer can be used as a map key.

However, it is pretty dangerous to do so. For one thing, the pointer is just like a random number to you. It comes from some memory allocation within the sdtio library, and you have no control over it.

second, if for some reason you deallocate the file handle (i.e. you close the file), you will keep using an invalid pointer reference as a key unless you also remove the file from the map. This is doable, but both awkward and dangerous IMHO.